# Swift double equation not work properly

Tags: swift

I wonder why following not work as i expect:

```
let testSum = 0.1 + 0.2
let testBool = testSum == 0.3
```

`testBool` in that case is `false`, how could that be possible?

Comment: Recommended reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @MartinR ok that's quite a lot, could you provide quick possibility?

Comment: Just convert Float, like below

 let testSum = Float(0.1 + 0.2)
 let testBool = testSum == 0.3
 print(testBool)